# Hilbert Curve and Spatial properties

Tags: special-functions

I'm trying to understand the following proposition about the Hilbert Curves:

> If (x,y) are the coordinates of a point within the unit square, and d
>   is the distance along the curve when it reaches that point, then
>   points that have nearby d values will also have nearby (x,y) values.
>   The converse can't always be true. There will sometimes be points
>   where the (x,y) coordinates are close but their d values are far
>   apart.

This seems to be a contradiction to me, if the mapping from `(x,y)` points that are close together doesn't maps to values of `d` close together, how can values of `d` close together map to `(x,y)` points there are close ?

Comment: Have you looked at pictures of approximations to the Hilbert curve?  The point is that the curve returns to nearly the same place at many far-apart times (close (x,y) but distant d).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement, an excerpt from [Hilbert Curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve) does seem a bit vague, but this is how I interpret it.  Say you have a space filling curve $\gamma$ in the unit square with a length $d$ that ends at $(x_1, y_1)$.  If you follow that curve further to a length $d + \epsilon$ you will end up at a nearby point $(x_2, y_2)$ because it is continuous.

On the other hand.  If you take two points $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2)$ that are close to each other, the Hilbert Curve may take quite a long excursion starting at $(x_1, y_1)$ before it hits $(x_2, y_2)$.  This is a feature of being space filling.